# Duplicate values in Julia with Function

Tags: tuples, julia, repeat

I need writing a function which takes as input

```
a = [12,39,48,36]
```

and produces as output

```
b=[4,4,4,13,13,13,16,16,16,12,12,12]
```

where the idea is to repeat one element three times or two times (this should be variable) and divided by 2 or 3.

I tried doing this:

```
c=[12,39,48,36]
a=size(c)
for i in a 
    repeat(c[i]/3,3)
end
```

Comment: You should probably split this up into two steps. `repeat(c ./ 3, inner=3)` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to vectorize the division operator with a dot `.`.
Additionally I understand that you want results to be `Int` - you can vectorizing casting to `Int` too:

```
repeat(Int.(a./3), inner=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Przemyslaw's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761653/3575047), `repeat(Int.(a./3), inner=3)`, is excellent and is how you should write your code for conciseness and clarity. Let me in this answer analyze your attempted solution and offer a revised solution which preserves your intent. (I find that this is often useful for educational purposes).

Your code is:

```
c = [12,39,48,36]
a = size(c)
for i in a 
    repeat(c[i]/3, 3)
end
```

The immediate fix is:

```
c = [12,39,48,36]
output = Int[]
for x in c
    append!(output, fill(x/3, 3))
end
```

Here are the changes I made:

- You need an array to actually store the output. The `repeat` function, which you use in your loop, would produce a result, but this result would be thrown away! Instead, we define an initially empty `output = Int[]` and then `append!` each repeated block.
- Your `for` loop specification is iterating over a size tuple `(4,)`, which generates just a single number `4`. (Probably, you misunderstand the purpose of the `size` function: it is primarily useful for *multidimensional* arrays.) To fix it, you could do `a = 1:length(c)` instead of `a = size(c)`. But you don't actually need the index `i`, you only require the elements `x` of `c` directly, so we can simplify the loop to just `for x in c`.
- Finally, `repeat` is designed for arrays. It does not work for a single scalar (this is probably the error you are seeing); you can use the more appropriate `fill(scalar, n)` to get `[scalar, ..., scalar]`.